# How to print from sh file

Tags: linux, printing, debian-wheezy, lpr

File prindi.sh contains

```
/usr/bin/lpr –P SL-M3325ND <teade.pdf
```

its inovoking returns error

```
/usr/bin/lpr: Error - unable to access "–P" - No such file or directory
```

If this command in invoked directly from command line it works:

```
# /usr/bin/lpr -P SL-M3325ND <teade.pdf
# lpq
SL-M3325ND is ready
no entries
```

How to fix this so that it can printed from prindi.sh also ?

Comment: The problem is the wrong kind of `-` sign in your script.  Replace it with a good old-fashioned hyphen, and `lpr` will stop seeing `–P` as a (missing) file to be printed, and recognise `-P` as a flag (do you see they're different lengths?).

Comment: I'm guessing from your response that that fixed it, so I've written it up as a full answer.  Please either accept my answer or delete the question (up to you which!) so it doesn't float around forever.  Thanks, and I'm glad you got things working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the wrong kind of `-` sign in your script (do you see they're different lengths?).

Replace it with a good old-fashioned hyphen, and lpr will stop seeing `–P` as a (missing) file to be printed, and recognise `-P` as a flag.  And whoever wrote that script should stop using word processors to write shell scripts, and use a proper text editor instead (there's a difference!).

Comment: Oh yes, the joys (and pains) of Unicode... . You can have similar types of fun with the different types of quotes.